# Group by single value in different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

My query:

```
select 
    cue.cod_cli, sum(cue.sal_doc) as total, cue.num_doc count
from
    cxc_cuedoc cue
where 
    sal_doc > 0 and tip_doc = '010'
group by 
    cue.cod_cli
```

Expected result

```
cod_cli      total       num_doc 
--------------------------------
47474747    450,30         4
```

The `num_doc` would be the total of number of documents that give me the total.

Comment: you should show your sample data and expected result

Comment: You have to use an aggregate function on name and age.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `sum(cue.num_doc)`.

```
select cue.cod_cli, sum(cue.sal_doc) as total,
       sum(cue.num_doc) as count
from cxc_cuedoc cue
where sal_doc > 0 and tip_doc = '010'
group by cue.cod_cli;
```

It is possible that you want `count(*)` instead.  Without sample data it is hard to tell.